# pass variable from function to function in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass variable "locationProps" from function to function. But I don't know how to send the variable and how to access the variable in the method.

```
function Daily({ locationProps = 2, root }) {
  const context = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const localization = useCallback(() => {
    if (root && cookies.get("location") !== undefined) {
      return cookies.get("location");
    }
    return locationProps;
  }, [locationProps, root]);
```

```
function dayData() {

  getSpeadsheetUrl=() =>{
    return config.prData[locationProps];
  }
```

Comment: Before I can help you, where is `dayData` located?

Comment: dayData is located in dayData.js and Daily in daily.js

Comment: just I want to call the var "locationProps" in DayData !

Comment: Is dayData a component? If so, you could pass it as prop.

Comment: no dayData isnt a component

Answer (score 0):

One way you could pass parameters through functions is using closures. Read more on [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

In your case:

```
// dayData.js

function dayData(locationProps) {

  const getSpeadsheetUrl= () =>{
    return config.prData[locationProps];
  }

  return { getSpreadsheetUrl }
}

// daily.js

function Daily({ locationProps = 2, root }) {
  const context = useContext(ThemeContext);

   // Now you can call getSpreadsheetsUrl, like this: getSpreadsheetsUrl()
  const { getSpreadsheetUrl } = dayData(locationProps);  

  const localization = useCallback(() => {
    if (root && cookies.get("location") !== undefined) {
      return cookies.get("location");
    }
    return locationProps;
  }, [locationProps, root]);
}
```